# Drawing multiple charts using for loop in bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh

I need to draw a couple of horizontal bar charts. I applied the following for loop to draw them, but I get an error

```
chart_cols = 'respondent_age respondent_gender respondent_edu respondent_occupation Religion Caste_cat CM_choice Likely_winner'.split()
for f in chart_cols:
    count = df[f].value_counts()

    p = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title='Chart',toolbar_location=None)

    p.title.align = "right"
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Number of respondents'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Something'

    p.hbar(y=sorted(df[f].unique()), height=0.7, left=0,
      right=count, color=Category20,
       alpha=0.7)

    show(p)
    print('Done')
```

Error

```
# TODO (bev) implement this

ValueError: expected an element of either String, Dict(Enum('expr', 'field', 'value', 'transform'), Either(String, Instance(Transform), Instance(Expression), Color)) or Color, got {3: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e'], 4: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78'], 5: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c'], 6: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a'], 7: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728'], 8: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896'], 9: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd'], 10: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5'], 11: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b'], 12: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94'], 13: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2'], 14: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2'], 15: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f'], 16: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7'], 17: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22'], 18: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d'], 19: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d', '#17becf'], 20: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d', '#17becf', '#9edae5']}
```

How do I draw multiple charts using for loop? The examples given in the documentation shows the same done for 2 plots using `row` function.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `color=Category20,` part? From what it seems it's a dictionary which stores colour palettes for different number of elements, so you need to get its corresponding element. Probably something like `Category20[len(df[f].unique())]`

Comment: I did that and got the charts of the same color, but please tell me why my code didn't work and why the one by you is working?

Comment: The above code worked, but it did not work for a chart having only two fields, for that does one have to draw a different chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works now.
for f in chart_cols:
    count = df[f].value_counts()

```
p = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title='Chart',toolbar_location=None)

p.title.align = "right"
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Number of respondents'
p.yaxis.axis_label = str(f)

p.hbar(y=sorted(df[f].unique()), height=0.7, left=0,
      right=count, color=Category20[len(df[f].unique())], alpha = 0.7)

show(p)
```